# How do I find the declaration of a webpage with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, declaration

I am trying to find the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag of a webpage with JS.

For example if the  declaration was `<!DOCTYPE foo>` I want to be able to find that with JS.

I do not want jquery for this.

I am trying to write somthing like on 
[this W3schools Link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GK0ZWWTFMD75)
But it does not work...

Comment: `window.document.doctype`?

Comment: Try `window.document.doctype.name` then

Comment: That has worked!